# How do i pass JSON data between 2 fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-databinding, android-json

I am retrieving my JSON as follows :
 myResponse.java :

```
  public List<Repo> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Repo> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof MyResponse)) return false;

        MyResponse that = (MyResponse) o;

        return data != null ? data.equals(that.data) : that.data == null;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = statusCode.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + message.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (data != null ? data.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    public static class Repo {


        @Expose
        @SerializedName("title")
        private String title;



        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (!(o instanceof Repo)) return false;

            Repo repo = (Repo) o;

            if (!id.equals(repo.id)) return false;
            if (!title.equals(repo.title)) return false;
            return description.equals(repo.description);

        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = id.hashCode();
            result = 31 * result + title.hashCode();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Now in my fragment 1 adapter I have :

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) itemView.getContext();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .disallowAddToBackStack()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left, R.anim.slide_right)
                        .add(R.id.root_view, Fragment2.newInstance(), Fragment2.TAG)
                        .commit();
```

This is my fragment2 new instance:

```
 public static Fragment2 newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Is there a way I can pass the attributes title and description I retrieve from JSON from fragment 1 to fragment 2 ? 
I would like to display these attributes in the fragment2 textview, but not sure what will be the best approach. Tried looking online but had no luck so far.Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your new `Fragment`, you want to pass in your data through the `Bundle`.

```
public static Fragment2 newInstance(Repo repo) {

    Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", repo.getTitle());
    args.putString("description", repo.getDescription());

    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}
```

And then within your `Fragment2`, you can fetch them again.

```
   void onViewCreated(View view,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Bundle arguments = getArguments();

        String title = arguments.getString("title", "");
        String description = arguments.getString("description", "");
    }
```

Comment: @Adice-Dog you are the best boy ever! Thanks for your solution. it works!